# Для элементов, расположенных ниже побочной диагонали, увеличить на 2 значения, если i+j кратно трем. Python

Tags: python, numpy, матрицы

Можно ли как-то обратиться к индексам строки и столбца для выполнения задачи, если при создании матрицы использовался Numpy

```
data = []
    for i in range (36):
        data.append(randint(1,100))
    print(data)
    n = 6
    m = 6
    a = np.matrix(data).reshape(n,m)
    print(a)
    
    N = a.shape[0]
    print(N)
    a[np.triu_indices(N, 1)] = np.power(a[np.triu_indices(N, 1)],2)
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array()
a[2] # строка по индексу 2
a[:, 5:6] # столбец по индексу 5
a[3, 2:7] # строка по индексу 3 со второго по 7 элементами (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) столбца
a[1:4, 1:4] # 1 - 4 строки с элементами 1 - 4 столбцов
```